# Google App Licensing for Beta Apps?

Tags: android

This is what I am trying to do:

- Put an app into a free beta
- Make the user have a time limit on how long they can use it for "Beta Testing" (Time Bomb But this is easy to get around)
- After the users beta time is up (Say 30 days) when the user enters the application [Or better yet they get a screen pop up when they start their phone]a screen pops up saying a message about beta being over, if you like our product please purchase the paid version.

So what I am doing is making a 30 day trial period on my application.

(I'm almost sure this has been done before, I'm wondering how to do it myself)

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way to detect the end of the trial would be store the current date using Preferences when the app first launches, and then compare that stored date with the current date (from the phone or from the internet) on every subsequent launch.

The user could just clear the application's data from Settings, or uninstall and reinstall the app, however, and it would start working again.

One solution to that is to have the app register the device, or the user's google account, with a server of yours on first launch, which the app connects to, to request permission on each subsequent launch.

A cheaper solution would be to design your app so that clearing its data or uninstalling and reinstalling it is enough of a chore to discourage users from doing it; for example, prevent exporting data from the app within the trial, so that the user has to choose between either paying or uninstalling the app and losing all their work.

Comment: As good answer as this is, it is info I knew already. I guess I'm more or less looking for a step by step into how to configure a server for that reason. -- I dont mean to come off as snarky or anything like that.